# Terraform "ping-pong" encryption config for S3 buckets

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Everything seems to work fine using Terraform, but for some reason after each apply it keeps removing and then adding back the configuration for server side encryption on all s3 buckets. If I apply the removal, it will just add it back next time I run apply.

Here is what happens after running `terraform plan` on my main branch with no changes made/deployed. Next time I run plan/apply it will add it back.

```
  # aws_s3_bucket.terraform-state will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_s3_bucket" "terraform-state" {
        id                          = "company-terraform-state"
        tags                        = {}
        # (11 unchanged attributes hidden)

      - server_side_encryption_configuration {
          - rule {
              - bucket_key_enabled = false -> null

              - apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
                  - kms_master_key_id = "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:123456789012:key/Random-GUID-ABCD-1234" -> null
                  - sse_algorithm     = "aws:kms" -> null
                }
            }
        }

        # (1 unchanged block hidden)
    }
```

**Possibly contributing:** I setup a S3 `state` bucket to keep track of what I have deployed in AWS: https://technology.doximity.com/articles/terraform-s3-backend-best-practices

My `state.tf` file:

```
// This file is based on the writtings here: https://technology.doximity.com/articles/terraform-s3-backend-best-practices
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket         = "company-terraform-state"
    key            = "state/terraform.tfstate"
    region         = "us-east-1"
    encrypt        = true
    kms_key_id     = "alias/terraform-bucket-key"
    dynamodb_table = "terraform-state"
  }
}
// The backend configuration above is added after the state s3 bucket is created with the rest of the file below

resource "aws_kms_key" "terraform-bucket-key" {
  description             = "This key is used to encrypt bucket objects for terraform state"
  deletion_window_in_days = 10
  enable_key_rotation     = true
}

resource "aws_kms_alias" "key-alias" {
  name          = "alias/terraform-bucket-key"
  target_key_id = aws_kms_key.terraform-bucket-key.key_id
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "terraform-state" {
  bucket = "company-terraform-state"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration" "encryption-config" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.terraform-state.id
  rule {
    apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
      kms_master_key_id = aws_kms_key.terraform-bucket-key.arn
      sse_algorithm     = "aws:kms"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_versioning" "versioning" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.terraform-state.id
  versioning_configuration {
    status = "Enabled"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "acl" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.terraform-state.id
  acl    = "private"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "block" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.terraform-state.id

  block_public_acls       = true
  block_public_policy     = true
  ignore_public_acls      = true
  restrict_public_buckets = true
}

// This table exists to prevent multiple team members from modifying the state file at the same time
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "terraform-state" {
  name           = "terraform-state"
  read_capacity  = 20
  write_capacity = 20
  hash_key       = "LockID"

  attribute {
    name = "LockID"
    type = "S"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can we see the code you are using?

Comment: @MarkoE Added to the original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, I was using an older provider in my main.tf. I had 3.0 set instead of 4.0 and I’m using the newer `aws_s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration` instead of configuring the encryption in aws_s3_bucket (which would have been more suiting to the older provider).

I’m actually surprised it worked at all! Must be some features in 3.0 that were released yet.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.0" # This was "~> 3.0"
    }
  }
}
```